# color and width of a line according to the value of matrix

Tags: matlab, colormap

I am drawing a lattice on matlab. I want specific lines of the lattice 
to have color corresponding to the values of a matrix I compute elsewhere in the program

```
for ix=1:Lx; for iy=1:Ly; 

xs=ix;ys=iy;            

if ix<Lx;

%nnn along x
line([xs xs+1],[ys ys],'LineWidth',0.0000001,'LineStyle','--','Color','r'); hold on; 

%nnn along y
if iy==1; line([xs+1/2 xs+1/2],[ys ys+1/2],'LineWidth',0.0000001,'LineStyle','--','Color','r'); hold on; end;
if iy>=2 ; line([xs+1/2 xs+1/2],[ys-1/2 ys+1/2],'LineWidth',0.0000001,'LineStyle','--','Color','r'); hold on; end;

end;
```

etc.

How can I make the color (red in the above snippet), and the width of the lines if possible, change according to the values of the 2d matrix D2mat(Lx,Ly) that I have computed elsewhere?

Thanks,

M

Answer (score 0):

It's no problem to set the `'LineWidth'` to evaluate or reference another array, eg `'LineWidth',D2mat(ix,iy)` or whatever.

For the color, what you want to use is first pick out whichever colormap you want to use, say we're going to use the `jet` colormap. Then you just define how many "unique" colors you want (not necessarily perceptibly unique, but it's the number of RGB triples you'll generate), then just reference them in your loop. For example we can define the array `colors=jet(30)` which gives us a 30x3 array of RGB triples. To set the line color in your loop just set `'Color',colors(ix,:)`. Now if you want to use `ix` and `iy` to set unique colors, as opposed to just `ix` as I showed, just do a linear index conversion with the two iterators.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used:   ' line([xs xs+1],[ys ys],'LineWidth',D2mat(ix,iy,1),'LineStyle','--','Color','r'); hold on; '  and got  ' Error using line Value should be a finite number greater than 0 '

Comment: I want to my line to have a color indicating the value of the D2mat(Lx,Ly,s) where the matrix D2 has been produced earlier in the code, i.e I want to produce a colormap for the D2 matrix which I will apply to the lines.

Comment: Re the line error, IDK, check to see if D2mat(ix,iy,1) is a scalar. Or the error could be  with [xs xs+1],[ys ys]. Re the color, I think what I said covers your question try and work with it, you haven't made your confusion any clearer